# Нужно записать данные в конец файла

Tags: python

Всем привет. Нужно записать данные в конец файла

```
import time
import json

from datetime import datetime

while True :

    with open("data.json", "r") as file:

        for line in file:

            json_line = json.loads(line.strip()) # парсим строку которую получили с файла

            notification_time = json_line['time'] # получаем со строки значение time

            status = json_line['status']  # получаем значение status

            notification_time_object = datetime.strptime(notification_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') # Превращаем time в обьект, что бы можно было сравнить даты

            if datetime.now() >= notification_time_object and status == 1:
                    if status1 == status:
                        status2 = 0
                        with open("data.json", 'w') as file:
                             file.write(str(status2))

                # status1 = status2.replace('"status":"1"', '"status":"0"')
                # with open("data.json", 'w') as file:
                #     file.write(status1)
                print('Alert! - ' + str(json_line))


    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: `open(filename, 'a')`

Comment: Опишите конкретную проблему, которая стоит. Весь этот код не имеет смысла без конкретной проблемы. Что, где и куда писать, а ещё важнее - что не получается у вас?

Comment: нужно чтобы в открытый файл json дописывало в конец данные, а не переписывало полностью файл. И я так понимаю нужно вместо w, a просто дописать

Answer (score 2):

Значения аргумента при открытии файла:

- r - открывает файл только для чтения,
- w - открыт для записи (перед записью файл будет очищен),
- x - эксклюзивное создание, бросается исключение FileExistsError, если
  файл уже существует.
- a - открыт для добавления в конец файла (на некоторых Unix-системах
  пишет в конец файла вне зависимости от позиции курсора)
- "+" символ обновления (чтение + запись).
- t - символ текстового режима.
- b - символ двоичного режима (для операционных систем, которые
  различают текстовые и двоичные файлы).

Попробуйте - `with open("data.json", 'a') as file:`

Comment: Режим "a" этот вопрос решил. Теперь задача в том, чтобы удалить строку в файле, которая только что записана в конце файла... Строка идет с значение 0( она вначале), но как она записана в конце файла с значением 1, её нужно удалить, чтобы была только 1 строка